# Create a new user from an entry submitted with the module "webform"

Tags: 7, users, webforms

i'm using the module webform  so that user can ask for the credentials to login to the site. I need to add a button to the the "view" of each submission so that the user that it's viewing that submission can create a user.

Do i have to modify the code of the module to achive this or should i write my own module? If i write my own module what hooks should i implement to add the button, the logic for the button to be present only if i didn't create a user, and the custom action for that button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am also looking for a similar solution and would like to reuse an existing one.
To assign a role on registration I would try some of existing modules.

Let me summarize what is available:

- [Auto Assign Role](http://drupal.org/project/autoassignrole) (D7, D6, D5)
- [Registration_Role](http://drupal.org/project/registration_role) (D5, D6)

#### To allow a user to choose a role on registration

- [User-Selectable Roles](http://drupal.org/project/user_selectable_roles) (D5, D6)

#### To provide a role using a key during registration

- [Registration Codes](http://drupal.org/project/regcode) (D7, D6)

#### Sold Memberships

- [Ubercart](http://drupal.org/project/ubercart) (D7, D6)

#### Join role with a password

- [Join role with password](http://drupal.org/project/join_role_with_password) (D7, D6, D5)

#### Apply for role

- [Apply for role](http://drupal.org/project/apply_for_role) (D7, D6)

#### Webform register

- [Webform register](http://drupal.org/project/webform_register) (see Open Issues for details)

See also [integration Webform and registration module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/7275/integration-webform-and-registration-module).

Answer (score 0):

Btw I've not used D7 in anger, so YMMV.

This is not a direct answer to the question :) but you know Drupal has a built-in mechanism for people to create accounts and then administrators approve (or not) them? I would've thought it would make more sense to try and customise that functionality, rather than trying to recreate it with webform.

A direct answer to your question is to check out [webform_hooks.php](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--webform--webform_hooks.php/7) and specifically [hook_webform_submission_actions](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions--webform--webform_hooks.php/function/hook_webform_submission_actions/7) which lets you create custom actions to be performed on submissions (such as the built-in *Print* and *Resend e-mails*).

Comment: The problem is that there are two types of registered users: thise who register normally and "verified" users that request a verified account with more privileges. So i need a contact form to request the username so that the moderator can verify that the user is who he pretends to be.

Comment: @Nicola Peluchetti I don't know D7 well as I say, but I understand you can add fields to the user account pages. Perhaps a way to go would be to add the fields to the account, and then have a custom submit button (or just a checkbox) that can signal that this particular user wants to be verified. Validation at this point can ensure sufficient fields are filled out. (If you still want to use webform I believe the links above are pertinent.)

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem like a Webform submission necessarily needs to create a new user completely. It sounds to me like you just need to have a separate "verified" role for users whose accounts have been separately verified. Poviding verification with a role will allow you to control access permissions based on user levels and is the appropriate way of handling such a task. This can be done with existing, well tested modules via a webform as suggested along with the help of [Rules](http://drupal.org/project/rules) and [Webform Rules](http://drupal.org/project/webform_rules). Simply create a Webform with your desired fields for allowing a user to apply for th "verified" role and upon submit you can invoke Rules actions to accomplish whatever is necessary - like sending an email to the site administrator or adding the "verified" role to the submitting user's account.